# How to get rid of memory leak in react web app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memory-leaks

I have this code in my ReactJS web application:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchInfo = async () => {
      const res = await fetch(`${api}&page=${page}`);
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const x = await res.json();
        if (page === 1) {
          setItems(x);
          setAutoplay(true);
        } else {
          setItems({
            hasMore: x.hasMore,
            vacancies: [...items.vacancies, ...x.vacancies],
          });
        }
      } catch (err){
        console.log(err);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };
    fetchInfo();
  }, [page]);
```

When this component unmounts while running asynchronous function, it throws an error in console.

`Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.`

How can i cancel asynchronous tasks in cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming here that `setLoading` is the function setting the state after your component has un-mounted, and therefore throwing this warning. If yes, then what you need is a clean-up function.

The function passed to `useEffect` can return a function, which will be called before the component unmounts (you can think of it as the equivalent of the old `componentWillUnmount`) - more details here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks

Now what you probably want is some sort of flag to check whether it is safe for you to call `setLoading`, i.e, set that flag to be `true` by default, then set it to `false` in the return function. Here's a good article that should help:

https://juliangaramendy.dev/use-promise-subscription/

Now I haven't tested this but essentially your code would look something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchInfo = async () => {
        let isSubscribed = true;
        const res = await fetch(`${api}&page=${page}`);
        if (isSubscribed) setLoading(true);
        try {
            const x = await res.json();
            if (page === 1) {
                setItems(x);
                setAutoplay(true);
            } else {
                setItems({
                    hasMore: x.hasMore,
                    vacancies: [...items.vacancies, ...x.vacancies]
                });
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        if (isSubscribed) setLoading(false);

        return () => (isSubscribed = false);
    };
    fetchInfo();
}, [page]);
```